# Pass value from Usercontrol to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I create a usercontrol1 with textBox. And with my form I add a usercontrol(the usercontrol1 with textBox) and a textBox. I already know how to pass value from Form to Usercontrol.

```
Form Code
public string ID
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
    }
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl11.ID = ID;
    }

Usercontrol Code
public string BorrowerID
    {
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
```

But don't know how to pass the value from textBox of Usercontrol to textbox of Form?
I found on how to close the form from usercontrol.

```
((Form)this.TopLevelControl).Close();
```

Change parentform color

```
this.ParentForm.BackColor= Color.Red;
```

How would i implement something like this or other method to pass value from usercontrol to form?

```
((Form)this.TopLevelControl).ID = ID;
```

or

```
this.ParentForm.ID= ID;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861496/transfer-value-of-user-control-textbox-to-form-textbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create the UserControl1 in a new project and reference it to my project that contains the form instead of directly adding UserControl in the form´s project, that's why things get complicated.

Here it now to pass value from UserControl to Form

**UserControl**

```
public string ID2
{
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxContent = this.textBox1.Text;
    var parent = this.Parent as Form1;
    parent.ID2 = ID2;  
}
```

**Form1**

```
public string ID2
{
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a property on the user control of any data type you like and set the value of that property on the web form containing the control.

User control Code-behind:

```
 public partial class UserControlTest : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return txtUcFirstName.Text; }
        set { txtUcFirstName.Text = value; }
    }
 }
```

==============================================================

MyPage.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div> 
                <uc1:UserControlTest ID="UserControlTest1" runat="server" /> 
            </div>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtFirstName" runat="server" /> 
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

============================================================

In webform code-behind,

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControlTest1.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    }
}
```