# How to pass value from Form to UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to pass a value from Form to UserControl.

I have tried to:
1.(and i make basketBox public)
Form:

```
UserControlBasket us1 = new UserControlBasket();
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    us1.basketBox.Text = g1.Name;
}
```

2.
Form:

```
UserControlBasket us1 = new UserControlBasket();
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    us1.Txt = g1.Name;
}
```

UserControl:

```
public string Txt
{
    get { return basketBox.Text; }
    set { basketBox.Text = value; }
}
```

3. And i have tried to do like here: 
[Pass value from Usercontrol to Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874853/pass-value-from-usercontrol-to-form)

I expect that in basketBox(it is a textBox) will be value from a g1.Name;

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: How many times are you doing this: `UserControlBasket us1 = new UserControlBasket();`. Each time, it's a new UserControl. Setting a property of this new instance won't change anything in the existing one(s?). Use the current (existing) control reference and set its properties.

Comment: When i click button in the form, the value must be written in the textbox in the usercontrol.

Comment: I use it only once

Comment: *I use it only once*. Maybe. Where/when are you adding this control to the Form's `Controls` collection? Why do you have points `1)` and `2)` doing the same thing? Setting the Button's `Click` event as `public` has no use. What is Button1 in both cases? Can you give these controls meaningful names, so it's clear where these belong?

Comment: 1) and 2) are just variants how i tried to solve my problem, they are not in the code at the same time. Button`Click event was created as public automatically.

Comment: The most important part is missing: are you adding this control in the Form's designer or in code, at run-time? If the latter, when are you adding the UC to the Form's `Controls` and where do you store the instance of the UserControl? If the Former, this: `UserControlBasket us1 = new UserControlBasket();` is a new instance, not related to the existing one.

Comment: I just place it over my form, it isn`t right?

Comment: Yes, of course. What is not right, then, is this: `UserControlBasket us1 = new UserControlBasket();`. This is a new instance of your UC, not the one that you placed on the Form. If you want your existing UC to update, you need to use its instance: do not create another one.

Comment: I just add a Controls.Add(us1) and it fix my problem, thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add a Controls.Add(us1) and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am just summarizing the comments (from @Jimi) with my answer here. Both the number 2 and 3 Solutions are acceptable and correct by design principles. It seems that a different object of user control was accessed here instead of using the one that placed the from.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should better use textbox, which is attached to page and dont use a UserControl.